# For email and other systems with "read receipts", is the word "read" pronounced "reed" or "red"?

Tags: pronunciation

examples of systems with "read receipts":

- [email](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email) (Microsoft Outlook, Google Gmail, etc)
- Apple has more than one: [Apple iMessage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMessage), [Apple Message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messages_(Apple))

> *If the recipient enables **Read Receipts**, the sender will be able to see when the recipient has read the message.*
> *Messages also introduced typing indication, delivery and **read receipts***.

- [RCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Communication_Services) messaging

#### For email and other systems with "read receipts", is the word "read" pronounced "reed" or "red"?

brownie points: for a good explanation on why.

Comment: *Read receipt* has its own entry in [at least one dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/read-receipt).

Comment: RE posting answers as comments: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-should-be-done-with-questions-that-have-been-resolved-as-a-comment-instead

Comment: The Wikipedia link for Apple iMessage says says its features include *getting **delivery and read statuses  (read receipts).*** Since it doesn't feature past tense ***delivered** [statuses]*, we can safely assume ***read*** is a *noun* (as in the "noun adjunct" usage ***read / write head*** for tape decks, computer hard drives, etc.). So it's pronounced REED, not RED.

Comment: I've been in the computer biz for 50 years, and I've never heard the term "read receipts" (no matter how you pronounce it).

Comment: @HotLicks Not at all certain it's meant to be named or spelled that way and automatic acknowledgement that a message has been received was once common, though separate recognition of reading now stretches my memory and why either faded away, I have no idea. To me, FumbleFingers analysis is flawed, if only because that detail wouldn't matter…

Chapters might be written and wouldn't the point still be whether the message had been read as in 'RED'? Doesn't the fact that the message can't be 'REED' matter most?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: The two possibilities are ***delivery** + REED statuses* and ***delivered** + RED statuses*. We know ***delivery*** is a noun adjunct whose scope extends to the head noun ***statuses***, since it would be daft to *explicitly point out* that delivery itself is a "feature" of Apple iMessage!

Answer (score 3):

Yours is a question about a fine point [without](https://www.mic.com/articles/130999/how-do-you-pronounce-read-receipts) a consensus, so I can only express my personal opinion in the matter. A *read receipt* informs the sender that an e-mail [*has been read*](https://askmixer.com/is-it-read-receipt-or-read-receipt/), whence the perfect/adjectival form of the verb, pronounced ɹɛd. I think the inventor of the term wanted to emphasize this notion of a completed event.

I prefer the past-participle interpretation because it makes the meaning clearer and less amenable to misunderstanding, *cf.* *read command*—a command to read something.

To counter the appeal by *FumbleFingers* to the analogy with *delivery status*, I will remark that *delivery* is not an event, but a process, so that *delivery* status reflects the current progress in the delivery process, which may be other than *undelivered* and *delivered*, such as: *sent*, *relayed*, *accepted by server*, *&c*.

*P.S*: Miss not the hyperlinks in my answer!

Comment: I wonder why this question was migrated hither from `english.stackexchange.com`. Proficient English speakers seem more interested in this than learners...

Comment: Don't you think experienced users see the Question as meaningless, while Learners think they ought to care… though in the end, they'll find they needn't have worried?

The Question itself might be a perfect illustration, which is to say that the word 'read' is almost never pronounced and when it is, neither speaker nor audience minds… unless they're not familiar with that part of the language.

If I expected to here 'reed' but you said 'red' - or vice versa - why would I mind? Only because I thought it ought to matter, because I was unfamiliar with the language.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, Meaningless? No, I don't think so. I am all for accurate English usage and against sloppy grammar, which arises from and leads to sloppy thinking by way of a self-sustaining loop. In my opinion, both learners and proficient users should speak and write knowingly, with a conscious awareness of the reason behind every syntatical choice. Utilitarians who think language good enough as long as it is understood by the person addressed are futhering its degradation.

Comment: Thanks and I though this was about pronunciation, not accurate language usage or sloppy grammar. At risk of being sent to Chat, what did I miss, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin May I suggest that you missed the point of the question, which is the grammatical form of the verb *to read* in *read receipt*: bare infinitive or past participle. The pronunciation is secondary in being determined by the form.

Comment: May I suggest it's rather clearly you who missed the point. Whatever interpretation you hope might be put on it, the Question clearly stated in both title and exposition that it was about pronunciation.

If you want to turn that into a reference to grammar - or even semantics -  why not Post a fresh Question of your own?

Otherwise, why not take the OQ on its own terms?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin But I told you why—because the pronounciation of *read* in that phrase is determined the grammatical form of that verb. No explanation is therefore possible without reference to grammar, and an answer wihtout explanation is an insult. *read* *is* a verb, for were it an adjective the phrase whould denote a receipt that has been read, which it does not. Once the *OP* understands the correct/preferred grammatical form, he can surely look up the corresponding pronounciation in any dictionary, but before that he is all at sea without a rudder.

Comment: That sounds like an argument you might might make in a debating society. Here, why doubt what I first suggested: experienced users see the Question as meaningless, while Learners think they ought to care… though in the end, they'll find they needn't have worried?

Answer (score 0):

Although *to read* is a verb, 'read receipt' is a compound noun. A noun doesn't change tense like a verb. It's a read receipt when you request one in the hope that someone reads (reed) it, and it has the same name when you receive one back to confirm it has been read (red). The tense should have no bearing on its name. Other comparable compound nouns use the infinitive form of verbs, such as *cheat sheet, run time, play test* etc.

If anyone is an authority on how it should be pronounced, it would be the tech giants that created them. *Apple* executives have referred to them as 'reed' receipts in [keynote addresses](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yjelKEE3LSI) (the mention comes at 1:12:20 in the linked video). *Microsoft* also calls the same thing a 'delivery receipt'. You might well ask why not call it a '*delivered* receipt', as it is confirming that something has been delivered, past tense. The same logic applies - it retains the same name at the point of request and after delivery has taken place.

Comment: Everyone I have worked with in the UK Civil Service in the last 25 years or so has said 'reed receipt' (and 'delivery' receipt').